What programming language was used in Dijkstra's response to Frank Rubin's article about "Go To Statement Considered Harmful"
The Wikipedia article about the famous “Go To Statement Considered Harmful” by Edsger Dijkstra also links:

an article from a Frank Rubin that tries to debunk harmfulness of Go To
and a latter letter from Dijkstra commenting on that article.

Dijkstra in his response writes something that resembles a computer language or pseudo-code. It looks like this:

I would like to know: Is this a computer language or pseudocode and if it's the former then which?

Note, there's a second question regarding Rubin's Article:
What programming language was used in Frank Rubin's letter about Dijkstra's "Go To Statement Considered Harmful"?

The notation used in Dijkstra's reply does look quite cose to GCN or Guarded Command Language, a 'language' Dijkstra developed during 1970s and 1980s to have a compact notation and supporting formal programming and verification (*1). Its base was introduced with his 1975 paper Guarded commands, non-determinacy and formal derivation of programs.
That paper already contains all shown elements like

if/fi and
use of special symbols like the

arrow to separate guard (proposition) from guarded list (statements) and
tall-rectangle to separate multiple guarded commands within a statement.




as well as

do/od and
multiple assignments


The only parts not present in that first paper are explicit block creation |[/]|, variable definition and variables other than bool (*2).

*1 - A bit like ADA meets APL :)
*2 - On a side note: I do really like his use of the semicolon as statement separator at the beginning of a second statement. This nicely resolves any ambiguity (read error prone) when adding at the end. In addition he always places it at the same level at the previous block marker, so reading is well guided, avoiding all those indentation/continuation wars C has nurtured.

You see a lot of this notation in his classic book on algorithm development, "A Discipline Of Programming" (Dijkstra, 1976).
